# How to convert a multiple file Lucene index to a single compound file index?

Tags: lucene

I have a Lucene index in multiple files format. What is the best way to convert this to a compound file format index in JAVA?

One way to do this is to create a new index (with writer set to use a compound file) and call addIndexes(<>). Is there a way to do this without having to create a new index and do a merge?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to create an IndexWriter on the existing index, set use compound format to true, and then optimize().  However, I'm guessing it won't be any faster than the approach you mentioned.